# How to represent a custom Python object as a string when used as an argument in another function?

Tags: python, class, object, matplotlib, repr

I'm trying to make a simple object called `Color`.  I want this to have the same functionality as a string encoded as a hex color.  It looks like it's working but doesn't have the same capabilities.

#### Edit: In response to the accepted answer below:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb, rgb2hex


class Color(str):
    def __new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        # explicitly only pass value to the str constructor
        cls.color = rgb2hex(to_rgb(value))
        return super(Color, cls).__new__(cls, cls.color)

x = pd.Series([Color("fuchsia"), Color("black")])
print(x)
# 0    #ff00ff
# 1    #000000
# dtype: object
print("Should be fuchsia but it's black", x[0].color)
# Should be fuchsia but it's black #000000
print("Should be black", x[0].color)
# Should be black #000000
```

#### Original:

For example, the following operations work:

```
print(color)
print(pd.Series(color))
print(to_rgb(str(color)))
```

but this does not:

```
print(to_rgb(color))
```

I can't figure out why this isn't working. I've tried this but it doesn't fit the case: [Python, represent non-string object as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039353/python-represent-non-string-object-as-string)

```
from matplotlib.colors import hex2color, to_rgb, to_rgba


class Color(object):
    # Built in
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = rgb2hex(to_rgb(color))
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.color
    def __str__(self):
        return self.color

color = Color("black")
print(color)
# #000000
print(pd.Series(color))
# 0    #000000
# dtype: object
print(to_rgb(str(color)))
# (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
print(to_rgb(color))
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda/envs/µ_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py in to_rgba(c, alpha)
    173     try:
--> 174         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
    175     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.

KeyError: (#000000, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-a478f942e1d2> in <module>
     16 print(pd.Series(color))
     17 print(to_rgb(str(color)))
---> 18 print(to_rgb(color))

~/anaconda/envs/µ_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py in to_rgb(c)
    279 def to_rgb(c):
    280     """Convert *c* to an RGB color, silently dropping the alpha channel."""
--> 281     return to_rgba(c)[:3]
    282 
    283 

~/anaconda/envs/µ_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py in to_rgba(c, alpha)
    174         rgba = _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha]
    175     except (KeyError, TypeError):  # Not in cache, or unhashable.
--> 176         rgba = _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    177         try:
    178             _colors_full_map.cache[c, alpha] = rgba

~/anaconda/envs/µ_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/colors.py in _to_rgba_no_colorcycle(c, alpha)
    225         # float)` and `np.array(...).astype(float)` all convert "0.5" to 0.5.
    226         # Test dimensionality to reject single floats.
--> 227         raise ValueError("Invalid RGBA argument: {!r}".format(orig_c))
    228     # Return a tuple to prevent the cached value from being modified.
    229     c = tuple(c.astype(float))

ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: #000000
```

Comment: You're supposed to actually show us the output if you have some print calls in your code... Also, what's this `rgb2hex`? That's the only part of the code we need to explain the puzzle. xD

Comment: Because your object isn't a string.

Comment: @ipaleka sorry about that!  Totally forgot to include the output.

Comment: As @juanpa.arrivillaga said, `__repr__` and `__str__` should return string.

Comment: That's not the issue, as far as I can tell they do. The issue is that function expects a string, i.e. `to_rgb`

Comment: it doesn't work because `to_rgb(color)` doesn't run `str(color)` automatically. As for me `to_rgb` see that first argument is not string so it tries to create tuple `( str(first_argument), second_argument )` - so it gives `(#000000, None)` - and use this tuple to get value from some dictionary and then it gets error `KeyError: (#000000, None)` - it can't find `(#000000, None)` in dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to subclass `str` to provide your string.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.colors import to_rgb, rgb2hex


class Color(str):
    def __new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        # explicitly only pass value to the str constructor
        v = rgb2hex(to_rgb(value))
        return super(Color, cls).__new__(cls, v)


color = Color("fuchsia")

print(color)
print(pd.Series(color))
print(to_rgb(str(color)))
print(to_rgb(color))
```

outputs

```
#ff00ff
0    #ff00ff
dtype: object
(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

If you want to store the initial value inside your string, you could do so

```
class Color(str):
    def __new__(cls, value, *args, **kwargs):
        # explicitly only pass value to the str constructor
        v = rgb2hex(to_rgb(value))
        return super(Color, cls).__new__(cls, v)

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.color = value
```

Comment: I've noticed something weird when more than one is instantiated.  I've added it into the original question

Comment: `str` is immutable. So what you did in the code is to change the color attribute of just every instace of `Color`. I updated the answer with what I think you want to do. (Also please make sure that the question makes some sense for future readers, who would usually read from top to bottom, not vice versa.)